# Does Angular.js work with Rails without needing an API?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, angularjs

I am very new to javascript and have mainly been learning  Rails previously. I want to be able to make more dynamic websites that give a more dynamic user experience but I am not sure wether to learn Angular.js or JQuery. I want to still serve the web pages through Rails and do not want to get into learning how to build a full SPA and Rails API and connect the two yet.

On the one hand I can see JQuery would be good for adding dynamic interactions to my pages but I have also seen that Angular.js is very popular and many people have told me I should go straight into learning angular. I also like the idea of being able to eventually make full SPAs with Angular in the future.

My main concern is I do not feel ready to start learning how to completely separate my frontend and backend using a rails API and a Javascript framework and would prefer to just add some interactivity to my pages and continue furthering my knowledge of Rails.

Is it possible to use angular to add small amounts of interactivity to multiple pages without having a SPA front end and Rails API?

Thanks for any advice.

Comment: Not a lot of point using angular if you are just going to create standalone server side pages. Trend these days though is to move away from standalone pages

Comment: Thanks for the reply. What would be the best library to use for this? JQuery? If it is still possible to use angular to do this I guess the benefit would be that I can ramp up my understanding over time and eventually start building SPAs rather than having to make the transition over to Angualar from scratch at a later stage. What are your thoughts on that?

Comment: Suggest going through each step of tutorial on angular docs site. Nobody can really give you guidance, you need to use what best fits your project(s)

Comment: So would you recommend starting with angular on standalone pages to add interactivity and then building my knowledge from there or do you think that it is better to stick with JQuery untill I want to make full API connected SPAs?

Comment: Build a simple app and duplicate using different approaches so you can make up your own mind

Comment: Yeh you could be right. I was hoping for some guidance but I might be best off working it out myself :)

Comment: Nobody can give you such guidance without knowing a lot more about what you are working on and that is too broad for this site. Can ask around on other stack sites

Comment: Yeh my main concern was wether it was advisable or even possible to use angular for adding small amounts of interactivity to stand alone pages

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Of course you can.
Add html pages to your public folder and put a script reference to AngularJS and you are good to go.

Comment: So in effect would this make each page run as its own seperate mini SPA? Just trying to understand how Angular functions because nearly everything I read references SPAs connected to APIs :)